# Android timer based service updating a database

Tags: android, database, timer, android-service

I am new to coding in Android.
I need a suggestion regarding timers and android services..
I need to update a database specific to my app once in 24 hrs...
The data base maintains a list of all files in the sd card...
so every day i scan the sd card and update for new files...
First of all is this a good idea or is there any other method to know new files added or deleted in the sd card.....
If the idea is correct, then how do i use the timers with the service class...

Answer (score 0):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule a PendingIntent that will trigger your filesystem scanning Service. If you want to receive real-time information for filesystem changes, use [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html).

Comment: i saw the file observer...seems a good option...but will a service associated with the file observer be triggered even if my application is not running...the application is only run when user starts it...but i need to have an updated database when the app is started...

Comment: If you use AlarmManager you can be sure your app will be started at given point in the future

Comment: is this right? I am not able to run the service though.... Intent callingIntent = new Intent("com.org.sdcard.MyService");
        
        PendingIntent sendingintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, callingIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager timermanager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        timermanager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,1000,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,sendingintent);